# setOnCheckedChangeListener cannot resolve symbol in Check Box

Tags: android, checkbox, cannot-find-symbol

I'm trying to make a button that is disabled until you check the checkbox

```
Button mButton=(Button)findViewById( R.id.registerBut);
    CheckBox mCheckBox= findViewById( R.id.checkBox);

mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mButton.setEnabled(isChecked);
    }
});
```

`setOnCheckedChangeListener` and `CompoundButton buttonView` says- "**cannot resolve symbol**"  ,
`new OnCheckedChangeListene` says - "**Invalid method declaration; return type required**"

If you could please help me solve this.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: why did you double star the names? Did you want to highlight them?

Comment: I fixed it so it is easier to understand

Comment: Can you add more details about how did you initialize `mCheckBox`?

Comment: well u need to import the listener and button and youremove the closing normal bracket in line 1.

Comment: I edited with initialization

Comment: nothing happens when I press alt+enter so how can I import it? Also what closing normal bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in your code unless you correctly `import` dependencies.

```
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

CheckBox mCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // your code
    }
});
```